# Codeigniter Eloquent superclass

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance, eloquent

I followed [this](http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added) tutorial and created a user model. I would like to create a superclass so that every model has the same timestamp value and a scope method. Is creating a superclass the correct method to do this? How do I extend a custom Eloquent model in Codeigniter?

I have the following idea, but i'm stuck on the custom model extends part.

CustomModel.php:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class CustomModel extends Eloquent {
    protected function getDateFormat() {
        return 'U';
    }
    protected function scopeUser($query,$userID) {
        return $query->where('user_id','=',$userID);
    }
}
```

User.php:

```
class User extends CustomModel {

}
```

I thought about adding a manual include inside the User.php file, but I don't think it is a nice solution. I also prefer not to autoload the `CustomModel` class.

Comment: Did you think about using  a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for it?

Comment: So you think I should make a trait with the dateformat and scope and then add a use line to all my models?

Comment: Either that or extend the eloquent model and make all you models extend the new model. Don't forget to `composer du` and using the right namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create core model with extending working model from that one. Create MY_Model in core directory with specific functionality you want to use in other models:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class MY_Model extends Eloquent {
    protected function getDateFormat() {
        return 'U';
    }
    protected function scopeUser($query,$userID) {
        return $query->where('user_id','=',$userID)
    }
}
```

Than extend any model from models directory from MY_Model.

Comment: I get an error: Class 'MY_EloquentModel' not found.

Comment: You need to extend `MY_Model`, not `MY_EloquentModel`.

Comment: I already have a model named MY_Model. I made a new model called MY_EloquentModel and made the User model extend it. I should be able to do that right?

Comment: Try with just one capital case after prefix i.e. `MY_Eloquentmodel` or `MY_Eloquent_model`.

Comment: I just put the `EloquentModel` class inside the `MY_Model` file under the `MY_Model` class. I admit that it's not the cleanest solution but I guess it will work.

Comment: Even, it is adviced method from CI head staff. Jim Parry says for MY_Controller should have all classes that you need as parent class included. Like in MY_Constroller you would have Admin_c, Public_c and any other class you would like to extend in your working controller. So it is just fine that way.